# Doubt whether to use "has to" in the sentence or not?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I am writing a software specification, in that I wanted to say something like below.

"When we close the **A**, all the independent application **Bs** called from the **A** should also close."

or

"When we close the **A**, all the independent application **Bs** called from the **A** should also has to close."

Which is correct one? I tried google translate. but for both the sentence I am getting the same translation. I am unsure which is the correct one grammatically 
and conveying the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is fine. The second is not because the words "has to" have no grammatical function.

Comment: Thank you. is there something that I can remember. So that I don't get this sort of doubt in future.